# Running Observed Power test in R

Tags: r, statistics

Is it possible to calculate observed power of ANCOVA/ ANOVA test in R? I could not get it right using [the 'pwr' package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html). Any advise on the right package to calculate observed power?

As an alternative, I ran the test in SPSS and the result is shown here:

[image: here (SPSS result)]

*The observed power results that I could not produce in R are the one in the red box*.

In R, I have obtained all of the numbers (e.g. p-value, partial eta square, F score). They are similar with the ones in SPSS except for the observed power. Images below are the output from R for the similar test.

### R output 1 - summary of the results

[image: R output 1 - summary of the results]

### R output 2 - detailed view of the results

[image: R output 2 - detailed view of the results]

### R output 3 - partial eta square of the independent variables in the model

[image: R output 3 - partial eta square of the independent variables in the model]

Any help/ hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than put links to images of the output in the question, please put the output as actual text delimited by code fences.

Comment: Replace the images w/ text, and it's a good question though.

Comment: Hi Joman and Aaron, thanks for replying. Sorry I am new to this community. Do you mind to point me to a thread that put 'output as actual text delimited by code fences' so I can replicate it in my thread?